# MonoDevelop - Breakpoints not hit

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.12 in Ubuntu 14 and have had no luck getting breakpoints to be hit in my C# application.

I am however able to break when calling: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

I saw this post (among other ones scattered about) [Unable to hit breakpoints in MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866207/unable-to-hit-breakpoints-in-monodevelop)

But already tried having the Run on External Console checkbox unticked to no avail.  I also do not see the 'Emit Debugging Information' option.  Using xterm as the External Console did not seem to work either.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to MonoDevelop 5.0.1 (added the stable version ppa) the problem seems to have resolved itself.